# Oracle Apex creating procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

1) Create a procedure (PrintProc) that prints out "This is the Final Test".

2) Create a procedure (UpdateProc) that takes a 'student Id' and then updates his State to ‘New York’.

Pic student database 
[image]
Pic of faculty database
[image]
For #1 is it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PrintProc IS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(’This is the Final Test’);
END;
```

To execute I did

```
begin 
   PrintProc;
end;
```

but I got an error

For #2 is it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UpdateProc
AS
BEGIN
   Update Student
   set s_state = 'New York'
   where s_state = 'WI'
END;
```

and got this error Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

to execute it is it

```
Begin
   UpdateProc;
end;
```

6) Create a procedure (PrintStudentsProc) that prints out a list of students who have been taught by Kim Cox.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PrintStudentsProc
AS
BEGIN
   Select S.S_ID, F.F_ID
   FROM Faculty F INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON F.F_ID = S.F_ID
   WHERE F.F_ID = 1                                                   
END;
```

and I get this error Error at line 4: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

---

Was about to make another topic about triggers but stackoverflow bugged out again and I can't post for -9 days cause I posted 6 recent(not even recent) questions.

5) Create a trigger (UpdateTrigger) that outputs a message saying "Student record is going to be updated” Before the Update Takes place on Student Table,

I did

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UpdateTriggers
BEFORE UPDATE ON StudentsInfo
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student record is going to be updated');
   Update StudentsInfo Set StudentsUpdated = StudentsUpdated + 1;
End;
```

and how would I execute it?

```
begin
   UpdateTriggers;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Error in PrintProc**

The error in following code:

```
begin 
PrintProc;
end;
```

is caused by the invalid character **’** in `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in `PrintProc`. Replace **’** with **'**, this should resolve that error.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is the Final Test');
```

---

**2. Error in UpdateProc**

The error in `UpdateProc` is caused by missing semi-colon in update statement. Add semicolon like the following:

```
Update Student
set s_state = 'New York'
where s_state = 'WI';
```

---

**3. Error in PrintStudentsProc**

Regarding the error in `PrintStudentsProc`, you can't do plain select statement inside plsql block. You need to use [cursor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_cursors.htm). Also, you are missing semi-colon in the following query:

```
Select S.S_ID, F.F_ID
FROM Faculty F INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON F.F_ID = S.F_ID
WHERE F.F_ID = 1;
```

Cursor for loop example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PrintStudentsProc AS
BEGIN
   FOR stud_rec IN (
       Select S.S_ID SID, F.F_ID FID
       FROM Faculty F INNER JOIN STUDENT S ON F.F_ID = S.F_ID
       WHERE F.F_ID = 1)
   LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stud_rec.SID||', '||stud_rec.FID);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

### Have a look at other types of cursors [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)

**4. Error in Trigger**

For trigger, after creating the trigger you need to execute the statement which invokes the trigger. In your case it is before update, so you need to perform a update query on the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_trigger BEFORE
  update ON StudentsInfo FOR EACH ROW 
  DECLARE 
        stud_updated int;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student record is going to be updated'); 
    select StudentsUpdated into stud_updated from StudentsInfo where s_id=:new.s_sid;
    --increase the value
    stud_updated := stud_updated+1;
    Update StudentsInfo Set StudentsUpdated = :stud_updated;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student updated count:'||stud_updated);
END;
/
```

The above trigger should be able to execute, whenever you perform an update on the StudentsInfo table.

Also, check this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e5fa/1)

Comment: Don't really understand the cursor part which I learned at the end of my last class. Was looking through my notes and tried to change it to a select statement with cursor but got error. Don't know how to format in replys. CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE addfive
AS
  CURSOR C_Capacity
  IS
  SELECT LOC_ID FROM Location where Capacity >=45;
Begin
    FOR REC IN C_Capacity
    LOOP
    UPDATE Location SET Capacity = Capacity + 5
    where LOC_ID = rec.LOC_ID;
    END LOOP;
END; is the example he gave which I don't know how to change to make it to select statements.

Comment: I took 4 hours to do the cursor thing and I think it's wrong unless there's multiple solutions. Argh and I forgot to use your trigger. I used my old one since it looked like it worked and it ran successfully. Thanks for the help anyway!